# ExtJS5 ViewController Listeners Not Firing

Tags: extjs, viewcontroller

I have the following store and ViewController:

```
Ext.define('WebApp.store.PraDataStore',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId: 'pradatastore',
    model: 'WebApp.model.PraDataModel',
    sorters: 'practicename'
});
Ext.define('WebApp.controller.admin.PraDataController',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.pradatactrl',
    requires:['WebApp.view.admin.PraDataGrid','WebApp.view.admin.PraDataForm'],    
    config: {
        listen:{
            store: {
                '#pradatastore':{
                    load: 'selectPraRecord',
                    add: 'addPraRecord'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    selectPraRecord: function(store,record){    
        console.log('Loaded');
    },
    addPraRecord: function(store,record){
    console.log('Added');
    }
});
```

And I am unable to figure out why the listeners for the store are not firing.  The store loads but does not fire the indicated method.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Francis, I am using Sencha's ExtJS 5.  It's how the API works.

Answer (score 1):

So I assume the view using this view controller is created before the store loads?